# Maximum, minimum and total numbers

Tags: python

Maximum, minimum and total numbers using python. For example:

```
>>>maxmin()
Enter integers, one per line, terminated by -10 :
2    
1    
3    
7    
8    
-10


Output : total =5, minimum=1, maximum = 8
```

Here is my code. I need some help with this.

```
def maxmin():
    minimum = None
    maximum = None

    while (num != -10):
    num = input('Please enter a number, or -10 to stop: ' )
        if num == -10:
            break

        if (minimum) is None or (num < minimum):
            minimum = num
        if (maximum) is None or (num > maximum):
            maximum = num
    print ("Maximum: ", maximum)
    print ("Minimum: ", minimum)
```

Comment: It looks like you are reading the numbers in as strings, but comparing them as ints. `"10" != 10` in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define `num` before you use it in the `while`, also your nested `if` should be out of the other `if`:

```
def maxmin():
    minimum = None
    maximum = None
    num = None

    while True:
        num = input('Please enter a number, or -10 to stop: ')
        if num == -10:
            break

        if (minimum) is None or (num < minimum):
            minimum = num
        if (maximum) is None or (num > maximum):
            maximum = num
    print ("Maximum: ", maximum)
    print ("Minimum: ", minimum)

maxmin()
```

Comment: Working with Python 2.7.3, if you give an `int` it's an int, if you give an `str` it is an `str`

Comment: No, you don't have to define num

Answer (score 3):

```
def maxmintotal():
    num = 0
    numbers = []
    while True:
         num = int(input('Please enter a number, or -10 to stop: ' ))
         if num == -10:
             break
         numbers.append(num)
    print('Numbers:', len(numbers))
    print('Maximum:', max(numbers))
    print('Minumum:', min(numbers))
```

Comment: Thank you. But it should not use any inbuilt functions like max, min and .append. (we can use len )

Comment: @Pramod You didn't say that in the question.

Comment: My apologies.. sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this:

```
def maxmin():
  minimum = None
  maximum = None

  while True:
    num = input('Please enter a number, or -10 to stop: ')
    if num == -10:
      break

    if (minimum) is None or (num < minimum):
      minimum = num
    if (maximum) is None or (num > maximum):
      maximum = num
  print ("Maximum: ", maximum)
  print ("Minimum: ", minimum)

maxmin()
```

See, you're not really conditioning your while loop aroud num != -10 since you check for that within the loop and break out of it. So, there will never be a time when num=-10 at the beginning of the loop, make sense?

So, you just loop forever (The `while True`) until someone inputs a `-10`

Answer (score 0):

This function should give you the output that you want:

```
def maxmin():
    minimum, maximum, total = None, None, 0
    while(True):
        number = input('Please enter a number, or -10 to stop: ')
        num = int(number)
        if num == -10:
            break
        if total == 0:
            minimum, maximum, total = num, num, 1
            continue
        total += 1
        if num < minimum:
            minimum = num
        elif num > maximum:
            maximum = num
    print("Output : total ={}, minimum={}, maximum ={}".format(total, minimum, maximum))
```